# Spring JMS | Queue messages and process themsequentially

Tags: spring, multithreading, jms, blockingqueue, single-threaded

I have a JMS listener wherein I receive messages and process the messages by calling a web service. Now, in case my listener receives too many requests simultaneously, my web service gets called as many times causing it to choke.

What I am looking for is a solution that allows me to queue (or hold on to) my JMS messages and process them sequentially. i.e only after the first message has finished processing, should it begin processing the other next one.

Here is some sample code:

```
public void onMessage(final Message message) {

if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
//Call the web service to process the message. Only after this message has been processed, try and process the next message.

}
}
```

EDIT: Perhaps, using a BlockingQueue could be a potential solution here?

Comment: With this you will be beating the whole USP of JMS async processing, why dont you limit the instantiation of number of MDB instances to your optimal need in server configuration.

Comment: @mhasan Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, in this particular case, we want to process only one message at a time. We are using instance of org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer and set the following property: <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" /> Is this whar you mean by limiting instantiation of MDB instances?

Comment: yes @va1b4av it should work